# Apache Sling Cache Issue

Tags: apache, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I'm developing an apache sling WCMS Application and using BitKinex 3.2.3 to upload
app files to the repository.

I'm struggling with a weird problem, so when I upload new app files to /apps no change will be occurred to the application and the application works without new changes.

I think this could be a cache issue!!??

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: You're not saying how you upload files and how you define "no change will be occurred to the application". Unless @notdang's answer solved your problem, you will need to tell us what you did, what you expected and what you see.

Comment: I used BitKinex 3.2.3 -as I mentioned- to upload (transfer) new jsp files to /apps and I expected new jsp files would be compiled but this didn't happen.
I tried @notdang's way and It worked truly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to /var/classes/org/apache/jsp/apps node and delete its content. In this case your jsps will be recompiled.